# Design implementation : Uploading XML file and evaluation of predefined path

Tags: c#, xml, database, treeview

I have a .xml file, which is the result of an export from a non-relational database.

In my application, as a configuration, a user should be able to select nodes from a xml structure, which would be compared/evaluated later on when he upload the .xml.

I have thought to 2 options, but am not very pleased with both:
option1: the structure of the .xml file has to be stored in the database, so the application can display a TreeView, and the user would simply select the nodes to inspect.
(cons: I have many .xml files, one for each system it relates too and each .xml is quit large)
option2: the user would have to upload a .xml file before starting his configuration, so that its structure would be dynamically generated.
(cons: User has one more step to do in order to make his configuration. The one .xml file that he uploads may not contains all the nodes it could have)

Or maybe there are different ways than displaying a TreeView for that purpose ? As it is hard for me to think out of the box, I can't see other options.

I hope this is clear enough,
Maybe there is a kind of best practices I have missed, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with an intermediate option.

Generate dynamically the xsd schemes corresponding to your xml files and store them somewhere.
Process all the xml files in order to have the most complete xsd, because you said that each xml may not contain the whole structure.